# ComoBox DropDownClosed is throwing exception while initializing Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to execute a command on ComboBox DropDownClosed but while running the App on initialization of that page it is throwing an exception:

> Cannot add instance of type
>   'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior' to a
>   collection of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection'.

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyCombo" FontSize="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyViewModel.MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,0" Height="56" SelectedItem="{Binding MyViewModel.MyAnotherProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DropDownClosed">
              <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyViewModel.MyCommand}"/>
          </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
     </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ComboBox>
```

### **EDIT :**

I searched for the possible reason for this error and what I found out is that I missed passing an element name

```
<core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DropDownClosed" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=MyCombo}>
```

Now it's throwing below error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Adding or removing event handlers
>   dynamically is not supported on WinRT events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.InvalidOperationException: Adding or removing event handlers dynamically is not supported on WinRT events.

I found the similar [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-CN/d2497ddf-9e7e-4cc0-995a-37730bfa6f1f/win10-uwp-2001325511202142035129992353022145722120-3246523450?forum=window10app) from [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4c9bc60-e72f-4577-a56e-0cae2d0cc0e2/tapped-event-for-grid-is-not-recognized-as-routed-event?forum=winappswithcsharp) and [github](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/681). And derive from JerryNixon, this will not work for you because the info events are not **routed events**. It is by design. Currently there is a workaround, you could use [`DataTriggerBehavior`](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/DataTriggerBehavior) to compare `IsDropDownOpen` property value to determine if the Combobox is open or closed.

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsDropDownOpen,ElementName=Comb}" ComparisonCondition="NotEqual" Value="True" >
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ItemCommand}"/>
    </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Please note, `ItemCommand` will be invoked after combobox loaded, because the default value of `IsDropDownOpen` is false. So you need do some logic to avoid this.